# Using PySpark to maintain a running word count of text data received from a data server listening on a TCP socket. Not receiving an output [Windows]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, spark-structured-streaming

I essentially want to maintain a running word count of text data received from a data server listening on a TCP socket. I'm using netcat to listen in on the socket, and running python in Jupyter Notebook to use Spark and calculate my word count. I'll include some links that can serve to provide more information on this project at the bottom of the post.

I'm completely new to Spark and netcat, so I'll apologize upfront if any of my terminology is misleading. I am running windows, and so I initiate the netcat session in a command terminal using `nc -l -p 9999`. After that, I run the following code in my notebook:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Assignment 7.1") \
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()

# Split the lines into words
words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)

# Generate running word count
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

try:
    query = wordCounts \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("complete") \
        .format("console") \
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopping query')
```

After running this, the code block never stops processing. What changes is that the terminal I started the netcat session in begins accepting text. Inputting text doesn't appear to yield any effect though. Here's a picture of [The terminal session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZpHf.png).

I tried ending the netcat session by hitting CTRL+C, hoping that would terminate the query running in my Jupyter Notebook and give me an output of the word counts, but that didn't work. Ending the netcat session did just that, and the code block in the notebook continued processing.

I'm wondering how I can get my word counts to populate. I really appreciate any help.

[Here is a link to GitHub containing the notebook](https://github.com/MrChadMWood/Misc/blob/main/Assignment%2007.ipynb)

[Here is a link to a tutorial on this project provided as Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example)

[Here is a 2min 30sec YouTube video of myself showing and explaining this issue in action](https://youtu.be/vAkK_9GJ2Cw)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with streaming data from TCP, I suggest you to try SparkStreaming. Here's an example of word counting

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

master = "local[*]"
appName = "Streaming"
sc = SparkContext(master, appName)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

#Dstream with real-time data
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
word_counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
    .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
word_counts.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```